# How to say "We shall see" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am trying to come up with a family motto as a birthday gift for my father.

We have a phrase we always like to say whenever we ask each other questions: "Will so and so become X?" or "Will we ever get to Y?" or "What'll happen when we do z?"

To which the answer always is: "We shall see"

How can this be translated into Latin?

Answer (score 8):

Can't really go wrong with a straightforward translation. The verb "to see" is *videre*, and encompasses this metaphorical use of finding out what the future will hold. So the simple future indicative 1st person plural active:

***Videbimus***

Cf. Seneca ad Luc. 75.5.1:

> Videbimus qualis sit, quantus sit.
> We shall see what sort of person he is, how great he is.

Comment: A Roman might ask: "quid videbimus?" Does "videbimus" stand alone--no context?

Comment: @tony Sure, as a family motto in response to a question.